# im learning flutter and using my pc and its working fine .. on the new pc when i try to debug it show this error only when i use AVD .. chrome is fine

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, android-virtual-device

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile$ActionExecutionException: java.io.IOException: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to create keystore.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

i added the java sdk to the enviroment path

Comment: you can try from a similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69917977/execution-failed-for-task-appvalidatesigningdebug-java-util-concurrent-exec)

Comment: your problem you can try from a similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69917977/execution-failed-for-task-appvalidatesigningdebug-java-util-concurrent-exec)

Answer (score 0):

First Run with --stacktrace and debug, there need to be debug keystore, which is used to sign in on Android. tyy this command,

> $ keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000